# Error when try to use bind of node-schedule

Tags: node.js, cron, schedule

I'm trying to use node-schedule, and I wanna use current data in future.
So my code is:

```
var j = schedule.scheduleJob({
       start: new Date().setHours(data[i].start_hour, data[i].start_minute),
       end: new Date().setHours(data[i].end_hour, data[i].end_minute),
       rule: '*/'+distance_run+' * * * * *'
}, function (data) {
       console.log("333", data)
}).bind(null, data[i]);
```

But it have error: schedule.scheduleJob(...).bind is not a function

Help me please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scheduleJob() doesn't return a function that can be executed. If you want to use `data[i]` inside the function, you can pass `data[i]` bound function as second argument like,

```
var j = schedule.scheduleJob({
       start: new Date().setHours(data[i].start_hour, data[i].start_minute),
       end: new Date().setHours(data[i].end_hour, data[i].end_minute),
       rule: '*/'+distance_run+' * * * * *'
}, function (data) {
       console.log("333", data)
}.bind(null, data[i]) );
```